# How to extract the tooltip text within an Angular 7 application using Selenium

Tags: angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver, angular7, webdriverwait

I'm trying to read text tooltip in  angular7 application via selenium. But get text is returning blank and javascript executor is returning null.

[Link to the image of the DOM for which I'm not able to find the xpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JkCd.jpg)

[image]

But get text is returning blank and javascript executor is returning null.

This is returning blank

```
driver().get("https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/tooltips");
Wait(3000);
System.out.println(driver().findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='tooltip-content'])[2]")).getText());
```

This is returning null

```
System.out.println(driver().findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='tooltip-content'])[2]")).getAttribute("value"));

String theTextIWant = ((JavascriptExecutor) driver()).executeScript("return arguments[0].innerHTML;",driver().findElement(By.xpath("(//span[@class='tooltip-content'])[2]")));
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be ("(//span[@class='tooltip-content'])[2]"), you are missing [] around the index 2

Comment: why you have given round braces out side of xpath

Comment: @LeyonGudinho ("(//span[@class='tooltip-content'])[2]) in get text which is correct

Comment: @akshaypatil the round bracket is there to print out the value

Comment: @LeyonGudinho    you  can use the link https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/tooltips  and on chrome you can see the xpath  (//span[@class='tooltip-content'])[2] it is highlighting the correct value on DOM but it is not able to fetch via selenium

Comment: I think you misunderstood, I meant to say that your code is showing [2] as 2, in your question.

Comment: .getAttribute("innerHTML") instead of getText() will do the trick. Also mentioned by  @DebanjanB in the answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To extract the tooltip text **Lorem ipsum sit** within the [Angular7 Application](https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/tooltips) using *Selenium* you have to:

- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *element to be visible*
- *Mouse Hover* the element.
- Induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired *tooltip to be visible*
- Then extract the *Tool Tip Text*
- You can use the following solution:

  - Code Block:

    ```
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

    public class Angular_ToolTip {

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Utility\\BrowserDrivers\\chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("start-maximized");
            //options.addArguments("disable-infobars");
            options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
            driver.get("https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.12/tooltips");
            new Actions(driver).moveToElement(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h6[text()='Small']//following::div[1]/a[@class='tooltip tooltip-sm']")))).build().perform();
            System.out.println(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//h6[text()='Small']//following::div[1]/a[@class='tooltip tooltip-sm']//following::span[1]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML"));
        }
    }
    ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Lorem ipsum sit
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: tooltip]