# Is automating angular7 application via selenium is good idea

Tags: angular, selenium, automation, angular7, webdriverwait

We have already a robust framework in place for automating the UI as well as customized classes for various other java operation like posting api, xml handling, file handling , json handling, database operation etc . Since there is a time crunch to switching to protractor and framework development is not possible.

So working with angular7 for selenium is good option. Since we can handle all the synchronization  issues via selenium

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a question in here .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First and foremost, the background context of the question *Is automating angular7 application via selenium is good idea* would have helped us to answer your question in a better way.

Perhaps there are no major issue reported while automating operations like *posting api*, *xml handling*, *file handling*, *json handling* as well as *database operation* etc of an application using [angular7](/questions/tagged/angular7) through [selenium](/questions/tagged/selenium).

When automating *Applications* exclusively using [Angular](https://angular.io/) [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) comes to our rescue to induce the much needed *wait* for the elements to be *present* / *visible* / *interactable* within the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

You can find an example of *automating angular7 application using selenium* in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412742/how-to-extract-the-tooltip-text-within-an-angular-7-application-using-selenium)