# Is there a way to click in Selenium (python) without selecting an element?

Tags: python, selenium, tooltip, webdriverwait, mousehover

I'm currently writing a Python program that automates a process for me on Google Chrome using Selenium. One of the buttons I have to press only appears when the mouse is hovering over it. Well, not necessarily the button itself, but the div that has the action in it appears when the mouse is hovering over it. The image for the button is always there. If anyone can help out, that'd be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: Please share your code and URL or HTML in text format

Answer (score 0):

You really don't need to *select* an element to invoke `click()` on it. Rather you need to use [`find_element()`](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_element) or one of the `find_element_by_*()` methods to locate the desired element inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_element_located()` to [**Mouse Hover**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57901045/scrape-website-with-dynamic-mouseover-event/57903003#57903003) over the element first.

Once the [Tool Tip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412742/how-to-extract-the-tooltip-text-within-an-angular-7-application-using-selenium/55414271#55414271) is clickable you can invoke `click()` method.

> You can find a detailed discussion in [How to mouse hover a parent element and subsequently click on child element using Selenium and Action class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384816/how-to-mouse-hover-a-parent-element-and-subsequently-click-on-child-element-usin/52386828#52386828)